# Need direction: saving form instances to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, local-storage

I've created a page that saves a form to local storage as JSON. It works as-is, but I want to extend it to save multiple days:
http://daverau.info/happy/

What are some approaches to saving multiple days worth of journal entries? Paginate the form data by date? Create multiple instances of forms? Should I start by ditching the dumbFormState plugin and handle saving to local storage differently?

I'm looking for options and hoping someone can point me in a direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the object data as I found it below:

```
[
    { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude1\"]", "val": "" },
    { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude2\"]", "val": "" },
    { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude3\"]", "val": "" },
    { "selector": "textarea[name=\"journal\"]", "val": "" },
    { "selector": "input[name=\"exercise_num\"]", "val": "" },
    { "selector": "input[name=\"meditation_num\"]", "val": "" },
    { "selector": "input[name=\"kindness\"]", "val": "" },
    { "selector": "input[name=\"tdate\"]", "val": "2012-3-23" }
]
```

Set the key to be the current date:

```
[
    { "2012-3-22" :
        [
            { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude1\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude2\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude3\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "textarea[name=\"journal\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"exercise_num\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"meditation_num\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"kindness\"]", "val": "" }
        ]
    },
    { "2012-3-23" :
        [
            { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude1\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude2\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"gratitude3\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "textarea[name=\"journal\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"exercise_num\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"meditation_num\"]", "val": "" },
            { "selector": "input[name=\"kindness\"]", "val": "" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Not knowing how efficient the API is, I'm just riffing here.. couldn't you stringify a whole object? That way the key for the localStorage item is actually just "happyApp" (or whatever), and the value is a nested set of objects that could be accessed via happyApp.date.

Comment: Poking into the API now and I realize that it's storing it on a per-origin basis, so you wouldn't need the happyApp namespace. I'll keep the comment in case anyone else can learn from my false assumption. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add the date to the `localStorage` `key`, or, depending on the data, inside the stored value (separated by a special character or by using a reserved space).

For example, the actual data could be something like this:

`"I'm feel'n pretty good today"`

To add a date, I could add:

`"032312I'm feel'n pretty good today"`

Then, it's just a matter of using `substring` to extract the date or data.